# Convert Normal Image into Progressive Image using Node Js

Tags: node.js, api, jpeg, libjpeg

Is there any way to write API which will convert normal image into Progressive Using Nodejs. I don't want to use Base64. 
I have done so much R & D on this. One library i found i.e lib turbo-jpeg
But in this only they are decoding the image .I want to encode that image too.
Please check this below link for reference. If anyone got any solution then please let me know.

Link  is - 
https://github.com/LinusU/cwasm-jpeg-turbo

Please help me out to write API to convert image into progreesive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [graphicsmagick](/questions/tagged/graphicsmagick) with [`gm` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) to convert supported image formats to progressive JPEG.

Here's a simple example (tested on macOS with GraphicsMagick v1.3.31 and Node.js v10.15.3):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');

const gm = require('gm'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm

const gmIdentify = gmInstance =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gmInstance.identify((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });

const gmStream = (gmInstance, writeStream, format = 'jpg') =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gmInstance
      .stream(format)
      .pipe(writeStream)
      .once('finish', resolve)
      .once('error', reject);
  });

// This function downloads the file from the specified `url` and writes it to
// the passed `writeStream`.
const fetchFile = (url, writeStream) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, res => {
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(new Error('Something went wrong!'));
        return;
      }

      res
        .pipe(writeStream)
        .once('finish', () => {
          resolve();
        })
        .once('error', err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  });

const main = async () => {
  // Download a sample non-progressive JPEG image from the internet
  const originalJpegUrl =
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg';
  const originalPath = path.join(__dirname, './original.jpeg');
  await fetchFile(originalJpegUrl, fs.createWriteStream(originalPath));
  originalJpegData = await gmIdentify(gm(fs.createReadStream(originalPath)));
  console.log(
    `Interlace for the original jpeg file is set to ${
      originalJpegData['Interlace']
    }`,
  );

  // Convert the downloaded file to Progressive-JPEG
  const progressiveJpegPath = path.join(__dirname, 'progressive.jpg');
  await gmStream(
    gm(fs.createReadStream(originalPath))
      .interlace('line' /* or 'plane' */) // https://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/Interlace.html
      .quality(originalJpegData['JPEG-Quality']), // save with the same quality as the original file
    fs.createWriteStream(progressiveJpegPath),
  );
  const progressiveJpegData = await gmIdentify(
    gm(fs.createReadStream(progressiveJpegPath)),
  );
  console.log(
    `Interlace for the converted jpeg file is set to ${
      progressiveJpegData['Interlace']
    }`,
  );
};

main();
```

It downloads [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg) non-progressive JPEG image and converts it to a progressive JPEG image and saves it as `progressive.jpg` in the same directory as the script.

Comment: If we upload png image then also it will convert into progressive?

Comment: Basically yes. But you should pass 'png' as the third argument to `gmStream` and change the output file extension accordingly.

Comment: Hey when i run your code , in my folder original.jpeg file has added. But progressive.jpeg file not added in my project folder

Comment: Something might have gone wrong. Are you running the exact same code as posted in the answer?

Comment: Can you post your os info, node.js version and graphicsmagick version?

Comment: Can you tell me if we render the progressive image in browser , it will show in progressive manner or just like normal image (line by line append)?

Comment: Progressive images can be rendered progressively. Graphicsmagick's jpeg encoder produces a progressive jpeg when Interlace is set to anything other than none. The way those images get rendered depends on the implementation.

Comment: In frontend we need to add any script or no need? Depend on implementation means?

Comment: There's no need to change anything in your code. Just serve the image and the browser will render it progressively.

Answer (score 1):

If someone just like me c/p @fardjad's answer and came across the following error, for me (Ubuntu 16.04) just worked to change one line:

```
(node:14862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify" "-ping" "-verbose" "-" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
```

From:

```
const gm = require('gm'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm
```

To:

```
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
```